# Multiple OR expression getting Error in PHP

Tags: php

I have one form with multiple submit .
form 1 :  $action="constregulation_add" and 
form 2 :  $action="constregulation_edit"
Somehow when i'm submit ,this action always ended in 2 validation in the code below. My question is when i'm trying submit in form 2 isn't that supposed to be just ended in Condition 2 (not include in condition 1 )?
But when i'm running this code ,why this code running in condition 1 too ?

Condition 1 :

```
if ($action == "procedure_add" or $action == "projectplan_add" or $action == "work_add" or $action == "form_add" 
        or $action == "template_add" or  $action == "imsdoc_add" or $action == "safety_add" or $action=="projectprogress_add"  
        or $action=="lessondetail_add" or  $action=="regulation_add" or $action="constregulation_add"){ 


        if (isset($_FILES['document'])) {
            $doc=$_FILES['document'];
            $extensionList = array("doc", "docx", "pdf","xls","xlsx","jpg","jpeg");
            $fileName = $_FILES['document']['name'];
            $pecah = explode(".", $fileName);
            $ekstensi = $pecah[1];

            if (!in_array($ekstensi, $extensionList)){
                $error[] = "<h5>* You're file not PDF or Word or Excel or Image JPG files</h5>";
            }
        }
        else {

            $error[] = "<h5> * File can not empty</h5>";
        }   
    }
```

Condition 2:

```
if($action == "procedure_edit" or $action == "work_edit" or $action == "form_edit" or $action == "template_edit" 
        or $action == "projectplan_edit" or $action == "safety_edit" or $action == "projectprogress_edit" or $action=="regulation_edit"
        or $action =="constregulation_edit"){   

        if (isset($_FILES['document'])) {
            $doc=$_FILES['document'];
            $extensionList = array("doc", "docx", "pdf","xls","xlsx","jpg","jpeg");
            $fileName = $_FILES['document']['name'];
            $pecah = explode(".", $fileName);
            $ekstensi = $pecah[1];
            $param="ada";
            if (!in_array($ekstensi, $extensionList)){
                $error[] = "<h5>* You're file not PDF or Word or Excel or Image JPG files</h5>";
            }

        } else {

            $param="tidak ada";

        }

    }
```

Comment: `$action="constregulation_add"` should change to `$action=="constregulation_add"`

Comment: I'm already fix that . But the result still same . Ended in 2 condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because on first condition last check you have only one equal sign. You should have two equals to check. Here `(...) or $action="constregulation_add" (...)` change to `(...) or $action == "constregulation_add" (...)`
If you use only one equal is always true because value `constregulation_add` is copied to `$action`. I think it's a typo.

Comment: i'm already fix that . But the result still same . Ended in 2 condition .

Comment: @yosafatwahyusetyawan Try to echo $action before first condition, after first condition and after second condition. To see if this changes. I don't see why should enter in both condition if you already changed = to ==

Comment: Okay ,i will do it,Daniel and Thanks for your suggestion .